# how to add one or more images in UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage, nsarray

I need to display one or more different images from array in one cell of UITableView like grid view without using any API for example three20 etc . Please  give solution for my question.

Answer (score 2):

This will put an image at the beginning of the cell:

```
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"]];
```

This image you can place anywhere on the cell by altering the frame:

```
UIImage *accessoryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"];
UIImageView *accImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:accessoryImage];
accImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[accImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width-70, 5, 28.0, 28.0)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:accImageView];
```

Comment: thanks for Answer my question ur answer works perfectly but i need how to display the image in grid view please give the solution for that thank you

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "grid view". There's no standard way to create a grid in a table, thats all custom, so if you could show some code that you are using, that will help me better help you ;-)